# LINQ -> XML Handle non-existing element-nodes

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm currently using Linq to parse an xml file as Linq takes fewer lines of code, but I'm having a small issue with in-consistent xml-files. I'm trying to parse out a Series class from an xml which is basically set up like this:

```
<series>
    <showid>5</showid>
    <showname>fringe</showname>
    <overview>description of the tv-show fringe.</overview>
</series>
```

And this is all well and good, this is easily parsed with the following code:

```
var series = from serie in xdoc.Descendants ("Series")
    select new TvShow()
    {
         ShowID = (string) serie.Element("seriesid").Value,
         ShowName = (string) serie.Element ("SeriesName").Value,
         ShowDescription = (string) serie.Element ("Overview").Value,
    };
```

But the problem arrives once i stumble over entries which doesn't have an "overview" tag... Is there a way to return an empty string if the element "overview" doesn't exist?

Comment: Solved it. I just had to remove .Value and then I could check the variables of TvShow for null variables :)

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely. Don't use the `Value` property - use the [explicit conversion to string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263.aspx) instead. That way you'll get `null` if the element doesn't exist, and you can use the null coalescing operator:

```
var series = from serie in xdoc.Descendants("Series")
             select new TvShow()
             {
                 ShowID = (string) serie.Element("seriesid"),
                 ShowName = (string) serie.Element("SeriesName"),
                 ShowDescription = (string) serie.Element("Overview") ?? "",
             };
```

(Obviously you can do the same for ShowName and ShowID too.)

Note that all of the custom conversions from `XAttribute` and `XElement` have a nullable version, e.g. casting to `int?` instead of `int`... they all work the same way, returning a null value if the original element or attribute is null.

Comment: And another obsolete attribute goes into my code per this answer. Slowly going through C# in Depth. Thanks.